# How do create dictionary that holds a string variable and three int variables

Tags: c#, dictionary, integer

I am trying to write some code that saves a name and set of records to a text file, and is able to be read and edited. I decided the best way to handle this was by creating a dictionary that held the string variable as the key and the three int variables as its values. However, I cannot get the specific code to work. It says that it cannot hold three values, despite it being declared a list. I have attached the code snippet below. It says the error occurs at the {playerwins, computerwins, ties} part of the dictionary.

```
private void FileWriter(string playername, int playerwins, int computerwins, int ties)
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<int>> records = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>()
            {
                {playername, {playerwins, computerwins, ties } };
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a collection initializer like this, you need to specify the actual list type

ie

```
new List<int>() {playerwins, computerwins, ties}
```

Fixed example

```
private void FileWriter(string playername, int playerwins, int computerwins, int ties)
{
   var records = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>
   {
      {playername, new List<int>() {playerwins, computerwins, ties}}
   };
}
```

Another option is to use a Named `ValueTuple`

```
var records = new Dictionary<string, (int playerwins, int computerwins, int ties)>
{
   {playername, (playerwins, computerwins, ties)}
};
```